# Hide form until button is clicked - Ruby on Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a content submission form on the home page of my app.

I would like to have it be hidden until a user clicks "submit an idea", at which point, the form should appear below the submit button.

I'm basing this off of the model used for replies/comments on Reddit, but I can't quite figure it out.

I'd imagine it involves jQuery, but I am terrible with jQuery, which is why I need your help.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Please try to implement something and come back with specific questions if/when you get stuck. Otherwise my answer below is the best I can offer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it with jQuery.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

 $('#form_id').hide(); //Initially form wil be hidden.

  $('#button_id').click(function() {
   $('#form_id').show();//Form shows on button click

   });
 });
```

Comment: This doesn't actually work due to a syntax error: You are missing a `()` next to the first `function`.

Comment: @meagar :  Thanks for pointing. Actually it was a typo. Changed now.

Answer (score 4):

Hide the form when the page loads:

```
$('#my-form').hide();
```

and show it when a button is clicked:

```
$('#my-button').click(function() { $('#my-form').show() });
```

Comment: +1, but why not make it `style="display: none"`, instead of hiding through `.hide()`?

Comment: Because the client might not have JavaScript enabled, in which cast the form cannot appear. If the form is hidden with JS as well, then having JS disabled has no effect - the form simply never goes away.

Comment: Hmmm.. good point. I generally refuse to work with the situation 'Javascript no enabled'. I just don't care about users who have such a problem.

Comment: Well, then consider this: Why would you do something with one technology, and undo it with a completely different, unrelated technology? The paired behaviour should be localized as much as possible, and hiding the form and binding the un-hide action in the same place in JS is *much* cleaner than a completely unrelated CSS rule off in some style sheet somewhere. This is less about the "what if JS isn't enabled" and more about just writing software *well*. This is undeniably better than a JS/CSS solution.